# jquery mobile disable button after submit

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile site in which a user uploads a file.  It works fine but the file may take a few seconds and i do not want the user to click the cubmit button again or think the upload is not working.  I need to disable a button after the user submits, I also want to change the button text to "Processing..."  Keep in mind this is jquery mobile because most of the jquery ways of doing this will not work with jquery mobile.  The below code does not work properly.  Any ideas?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( '#button1' ).click( function() { 
    $('#button1' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled').button('disable');
    $('#button1').prev('span').find('span.ui-btn-text').text("Processing..."); 
});
</script>

<form name="myform" action="gohere.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="file" name="fileName" id="fileName">

    <button type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" >Upload</button>
</form>
```